# Amazon EC2 - Issue Connecting to Public DNS 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, public

I cannot connect to my public dns which is a windows web server thru the internet, the public dns is

??????

I have a security group that allows HTTP for port 80 for for source ANYWHERE for both INBOUND and OUTBOUND.

I can rdp into the server and when I use http://localhost I can see my nginx page.

I was hoping to see the nginx page from public dns ????? but I can't!

My webserver is in a public subnet within a VPC

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Could you please verify that firefall not enabled on your windows machine?

Comment: @thirty i wouldn't recommend posting the server real IP's. It's not really required to help solve the problem.

Comment: it does look like the firewall is turned on, my friend created a similiar windows server instance though with nginx installed and i can see his publin dns and when i put it into google his nginx page is displayed, he has same security settings as me

Comment: By default port 80 is disable in the win firewall configuration. Just verify that it's enable.